# How do we encourage users to write reviews on product details pages

Tags: design, e-commerce, user-expectation, users

We're re-designing the product details page of a fashion e-commerce website. Until now we still haven't been able to get customers to consistently write product reviews. One way that we do this is send the user an email after delivery to write a review. A problem in retail apparel is the products that go out of stock aren't replaced but instead newer different products come in. So any product reviews written are no longer relevant. one idea would be move these reviews under the brand of the product since that rarely changes but we haven't seen this method being used. any suggestions or experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suggestion makes sense, you'd just need to clearly label the review type e.g. **Recent Reviews for Jackets** followed by some reviews. Alternatively you could have a generic review row at the bottom of your products which is populated with a variety of feedback your users have offered but just not specific to the individual item.

This may not really help as it's not specific enough so perhaps **a social media angle could work**:

You could ask your users to tweet about the product one receiving it with a product specific hashtag e.g. #H&MPinkCoat and then scan twitter for the tag and populate the reviews section with 'Product tweets'. This would take a bit of trial and error to get right and would like need some moderation...but so do reviews. You could incentivise the tweets by offering random prizes to people using hashtags and if you favourite peoples tweets they'll like that also as you're engaging with them (even though this could be automated).